# Send files to a bot in Microsoft Teams

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to send image files to a bot in Microsoft Teams. The problem is that the "upload" button doesn't show up in the personal scope.

I've added the supportsFiles tag in the manifest and incremented the version so that it triggers the changes when reinstalled.
Here is my manifest:

```
{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.3/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
"manifestVersion": "1.3",
"version": "1.0.1",
"id": "738xxxxxxxx",
"packageName": "-",
"developer": {
    "name": "AAA",
    "websiteUrl": "https://aaa.azurewebsites.net",
    "privacyUrl": "https://aaa.azurewebsites.net",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://aaa.azurewebsites.net"
},
"icons": {
    "color": "color.png",
    "outline": "outline.png"
},
"name": {
    "short": "Asistente Virtual",
    "full": "Asistente Virtual en Teams"
},
"description": {
    "short": "VA",
    "full": "VA en Teams"
},
"accentColor": "#267938",
"bots": [
    {
        "botId": "95dbxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "scopes": [
            "personal",
            "team"                
        ],
        "supportsFiles": true
    }
],
"permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
],
"validDomains": []
}
```

I cannot find anything else in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-files#configure-your-bot-to-support-files) that could be causing the problem.

EDIT: I've realized that in the "About tab" in chat (personal scope) still appears the old version (1.0.0). But if I access my bot through my apps it shows version 1.0.1. In any case, the "upload" button doesn't show up.

Comment: Could you please uninstall your bot from Personal scope as well as Team scope once and try again? We recommend [App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-app-studio) to create your manifest.

Comment: How do I do that? I can uninstall the bot from my Team scope but in the Personal scope I only have the following options: "pin", "hide conversation", "block bot" and "mark as unread". If I block it, it doesn't dissapear and if I hide it everytime I try to start a conversation it just simply unhide the old conversation. Also, I created my manifest in the first place with App Studio, should I update it also with it? Thank you!

Comment: You could uninstall your personal app from [Personal Apps section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oa3It.png) in left rail.

Comment: I did that. I uninstalled the bot from all the teams it was deployed. I created a new app with App Studio (new version, new name but same MicrosoftAppId since I only have that one) and still the button is missing...

Comment: Could you please share your App Manifest?

Comment: I just updated my message with the complete manifest (without real ids). Thank you

Comment: Could you please ask someone else in your team to install this app and see if he/she is getting option to upload? If you want, I can do that if you share the Bot id.

Comment: Hi, we have the same issue, were you able to solve this?

Comment: Hello Konrad. I'm afraid I couldn't test the last thing that Wajeed told me. You can try that and see if that solves the issue.